# autocmd changes only applying to new files

Tags: autocmd, abbreviations

I've been going through [learn vim the hard way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com)  and am currently adding abbreviations via autocmd.

I've added the following to my .vimrc

```
augroup outputs
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType php        :iabbrev <buffer> sout echo "";
    autocmd FileType javascript :iabbrev <buffer> sout console.log();<esc>hi
augroup END
```

which works, but only for new files. If I edit an existing .js or .php file it uses a cached version(I'm assuming) of the command before I editted it.

I was under the impression autocmd! would clear any existing commands. I've also tried adding abclear or running :abclear neither of which are allowing changes to the abbreviations to work on existing files.

Additonal troubleshooting:
if I run :abbreviate on an existing file it shows the older version of the abbreviation.
However, doing :abclear or :unabbreviate sout does not remove the entry on :abbreviate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I edit an existing .js or .php file it uses a cached version(I'm assuming) of the command before I editted it.
>   I was under the impression autocmd! would clear any existing commands.

`autocmd!` will clear the autocmds in the current augroup, but it will not undo any abbreviation, command, mapping, match, option they installed.

To install your buffer-local abbreviation via your autocmd, you can:

- reload the buffer by executing `:e`
- reassign the value of the `'filetype'` option by executing `:let &ft=&ft`
- apply your autocmd manually by executing `:doautocmd outputs filetype`

---

> Additonal troubleshooting: if I run :abbreviate on an existing file it shows the older version of the abbreviation. However, doing :abclear or :unabbreviate sout does not remove the entry on :abbreviate

`:abclear`, and `:unabbreviate`, will remove global abbreviations.
If you want to remove the buffer-local ones instead, you should use the `<buffer>` argument:

```
" remove all buffer-local abbreviations
:abclear <buffer>

" remove all buffer-local abbreviations in insert mode only (but not in command-line mode)
:iabclear <buffer>

" remove all the 'sout' buffer-local abbreviations
:unabbreviate <buffer> sout

" remove the 'sout' buffer-local abbreviation in insert mode only
:iunabbrev <buffer> sout
```

---

If you don't want the rhs of your abbreviation to be affected by mappings, use the non-recursive version of `:iabbrev`, i.e. `:inoreabbrev`.

---

In the abbreviations table printed by `:abbreviate`, you can check whether an abbreviation is local to a buffer and whether its rhs can be remapped by looking at the symbol(s) between the lhs and rhs.
If you can read `@`, it means the abbreviation is local to the buffer.
If you can read `*`, it means the rhs of the abbreviation can't be remapped.

---

You could also move your abbreviations in filetype plugins.
For javascript, you could use `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` and for php `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`.

In a filetype plugin, you don't need autocmds anymore, you can write your abbreviations directly:

```
inoreabbrev <buffer> sout echo "";
inoreabbrev <buffer> sout console.log();<esc>hi
```

Also, it would allow you to make Vim remove the abbreviations automatically if you changed the filetype of your buffer.
To do that, you would need to include a command such as `:iunabbrev` in `b:undo_ftplugin` (see `:h undo_ftplugin`):

```
let b:undo_ftplugin = get(b:, 'undo_ftplugin', '')
    \ .(empty(get(b:, 'undo_ftplugin', '')) ? '' : '|')
    \ ."
    \   exe 'iuna <buffer> sout'
    \ | exe 'iuna <buffer> ...'
    \ | ...
    \ "
```

Comment: File type plugins look like exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!